# Argument "partial" of the sort function in R

Tags: r, sorting

`?sort` states that the `partial` argument may be `NULL` or a vector of indices for partial sorting.

I tried:

```
x <- c(1,3,5,2,4,6,7,9,8,10)
sort(x)
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
sort(x, partial=5)
## [1]  1  3  4  2  5  6  7  9  8 10
sort(x, partial=2)
## [1]  1  2  5  3  4  6  7  9  8 10
sort(x, partial=4)
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  9  8 10
```

I am not sure what `partial` means when sorting a vector.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting

Comment: so in breif, for sort(x, partial=m) means arrange the vector x such that its first m position contain the m smallest elements (in ascending order.) <<< not necessary in ascending order?

Comment: The meaning of `partial` in R's `sort` is quite different from the one presented in an Wikipedia article, see below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As `?sort` states,

> *If partial is not NULL, it is taken to contain indices of elements of the result
>   which are to be placed in their correct positions in the sorted array by partial sorting.*

In other words, the following assertion is always true:

```
 stopifnot(sort(x, partial=pt_idx)[pt_idx] == sort(x)[pt_idx])
```

for any `x` and `pt_idx`, e.g.

```
 x <- sample(100) # input vector
 pt_idx <- sample(1:100, 5) # indices for partial arg
```

This behavior is different from the one defined in the [Wikipedia article on partial sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_sorting). In R `sort()`'s case we are not necessarily computing *k* smallest elements.

For example, if

```
print(x)
##  [1]  91  85  63  80  71  69  20  39  78  67  32  56  27  79   9  66  88  23  61  75  68  81  21  90  36  84  11   3  42  43
##  [31]  17  97  57  76  55  62  24  82  28  72  25  60  14  93   2 100  98  51  29   5  59  87  44  37  16  34  48   4  49  77
##  [61]  13  95  31  15  70  18  52  58  73   1  45  40   8  30  89  99  41   7  94  47  96  12  35  19  38   6  74  50  86  65
##  [91]  54  46  33  22  26  92  53  10  64  83
```

and

```
pt_idx
## [1]  5 54 58 95  8
```

then

```
sort(x, partial=pt_idx)
##  [1]   1   3   2   4   5   6   7   8  11  12   9  10  13  15  14  16  17  18  23  30  31  27  21  32  36  34  35  19  20  37
## [31]  38  33  29  22  26  25  24  28  39  41  40  42  43  48  46  44  45  47  51  50  52  49  53  54  57  56  55  58  59  60
## [61]  62  64  63  61  65  66  70  72  73  69  68  71  67  79  78  82  75  81  80  77  76  74  89  85  88  87  83  84  86  90
## [91]  92  93  91  94  95  96  97  99 100  98
```

Here `x[5]`, `x[54]`, ..., `x[8]` are placed in their correct positions - and we cannot say anything else about the remaining elements. HTH.

**EDIT**: Partial sorting may reduce the sorting time, of course if you are interested in e.g. finding only some of the order statistics.

```
require(microbenchmark)
x <- rnorm(100000)
microbenchmark(sort(x, partial=1:10)[1:10], sort(x)[1:10])
## Unit: milliseconds
##                           expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
##  sort(x, partial = 1:10)[1:10]  2.342806  2.366383  2.393426  3.631734 44.00128   100
##                  sort(x)[1:10] 16.556525 16.645339 16.745489 17.911789 18.13621   100
```

Comment: Whats the reason to employ partial sort? Reduce calculation time?

Comment: It is difficult (for me) to find any other reason (perhaps others may indicate some arguments?). See the edited answer for a benchmark.

Comment: Thx again for yr answer. The reason trigger me to think this question is that i found that partial sort within median function.

Comment: @Acqua has noted a critical correction to this answer, which I'll add as my own answer so I have access more syntax highlighting and formatting

Answer (score 3):

regarding the statement "Here x[5], x[54], ..., x[8] are placed in their correct positions", I don't think it's correct, it should be "in the result, i.e. sorted x, result[5], result[54],.....,result[8], will be placed with right values from x."

quote from R manual:

> If partial is not NULL, it is taken to contain indices of elements of
>   the result which are to be placed in their correct positions in the
>   sorted array by partial sorting. For each of the result values in a
>   specified position, any values smaller than that one are guaranteed to
>   have a smaller index in the sorted array and any values which are
>   greater are guaranteed to have a bigger index in the sorted array.