# Decreasing Partial Sorting

Tags: r, sorting

As `?sort` said, if the argument **partial** is not NULL, it is taken to contain indices of elements of the result which are to be placed in their correct positions in the sorted array by partial sorting. You can read [Argument “partial” of the sort function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23579012/10068985)
 for detail. So in the case that I need to find **the smallest 5 numbers** in `x <- sample(1:100, 50)`, then

```
sort(x, partial = 1:5)[1:5]
```

will be **faster** than

```
sort(x)[1:5]
```

However, how could I find **the largest 5 numbers** with partial sorting? Intuitively, I try to use:

```
sort(x, partial = 1:5, decreasing = T)
```

but it gets

> Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
>     unsupported options for partial sorting

Therefore, my question is how to achieve the effect of **efficiency** in this case.

Comment: `decreasing` in `?sort` mentions `Not available for partial sorting.`

Comment: Yes, I see. Therefore my question is how to achieve the effect of efficiency in this case.

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453326/fastest-way-to-find-second-third-highest-lowest-value-in-vector-or-column)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take the tail from the sorted vector:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- sample(1:100, 50)
# sort(x, partial = 1:5)[1:5] ## head

p <- length(x)+1 - (1:5) ## tail
sort(x, partial = p)[p]
```

If you want you can reverse the result using `rev()`

Comment: I think this is the correct solution. I just remembered this option after posting my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It's definitely what I want.

Answer (score 6):

You might still benefit from the speed boost with something like (assuming numeric data):

```
-sort(-x, partial = 1:5)[1:5]
```

---

Benchmarking:

```
set.seed(3)
x <- sample(1:100000, 500000, replace = TRUE)

bench::mark(
  snoram = -sort(-x, partial = 1:5)[1:5],
  OP = sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1:5],
  sotos_check = x[order(x, decreasing = TRUE)][1:5],
  jogo = {p <- length(x) - 0:4; sort(x, partial = p)[p]}
)
# A tibble: 4 x 14
  expression       min     mean   median      max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr total_time result    memory             time     gc               
  <chr>       <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>   <bch:tm> <list>    <list>             <list>   <list>           
1 snoram        6.87ms   7.77ms   7.43ms  15.04ms     129.     5.72MB     9    34      264ms <int [5]> <Rprofmem [3 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [43 x 3]>
2 OP            17.4ms  18.96ms  18.56ms  24.37ms      52.7    3.81MB     3    21      398ms <int [5]> <Rprofmem [2 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [24 x 3]>
3 sotos_check  14.65ms  17.07ms  16.48ms  25.58ms      58.6    3.81MB     4    23      393ms <int [5]> <Rprofmem [2 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [27 x 3]>
4 jogo          4.98ms   5.45ms   5.35ms   8.91ms     184.     3.81MB     6    37      201ms <int [5]> <Rprofmem [2 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [43 x 3]>
```

Comment: Can you also add `order` in the benchmarking? i.e. `x[order(x, decreasing = TRUE)][1:5]`...just curious :)

Comment: @Sotos, just added that.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and comparison with one another!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use C++'s `partial_sort` through Rcpp with a file with the following content:

```cpp
include "Rcpp.h"
#include <algorithm>
using namespace Rcpp;

inline bool rev_comp(double const i, double const j){ 
  return i > j; 
}

// [[Rcpp::export(rng = false)]]
NumericVector cpp_partial_sort(NumericVector x, unsigned const k) {
  if(k >= x.size() or k < 1)
    throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid k");
  if(k + 1 == x.size())
    return x;
  
  NumericVector out = clone(x);
  std::partial_sort(&out[0], &out[k + 1], &out[x.size() - 1], rev_comp);
  return out;
}
```

We can now confirm that we get the same and make a benchmark:

```r
# simulate data
set.seed(2)
x <- rnorm(10000)

# they all give the same
rk <- 5
setdiff(cpp_partial_sort(x, rk)[1:rk], 
        -sort(-x, partial = 1:rk)[1:rk])
#R> numeric(0)
setdiff(cpp_partial_sort(x, rk)[1:rk], 
        sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1:5])
#R> numeric(0)
setdiff(cpp_partial_sort(x, rk)[1:rk], 
        x[order(x, decreasing = TRUE)][1:rk])
#R> numeric(0)
setdiff(cpp_partial_sort(x, rk)[1:rk], 
        { p <- length(x) - 0:(rk - 1); sort(x, partial = p)[p] })
#R> numeric(0)

# benchmark 
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  cpp = cpp_partial_sort(x, rk)[1:rk], 
  snoram = -sort(-x, partial = 1:5)[1:5],
  OP = sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[1:5],
  sotos_check = x[order(x, decreasing = TRUE)][1:5],
  jogo = {p <- length(x) - 0:4; sort(x, partial = p)[p]}, times = 1000)
#R> Unit: microseconds
#R>         expr   min    lq  mean median  uq  max neval
#R>          cpp  23.7  26.1  32.2     27  28 4384  1000
#R>       snoram 174.3 185.2 208.3    188 194 3968  1000
#R>           OP 528.6 558.4 595.9    562 574 4630  1000
#R>  sotos_check 474.9 504.4 550.7    507 519 4446  1000
#R>         jogo 172.1 182.1 194.7    186 190 3744  1000
```

There is the compilation time but this can be offset if `cpp_partial_sort` is called many times. The solution can possibly made more generic with a template version [like I show here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64832567/5861244).