# Extract largest n values and their indices from a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, max, rcpp

I have a matrix that is approximately 150'000 x 150'000 from which I need to extract the largest n values and their indices. n will also be large, somewhere between 10 million to 50 million.

I can't do this within 'normal' `R` (like `data.table`) since if I convert the matrix to long format, it will have more than 2^31 rows. Could someone help with an `Rcpp` implementation of this?

I've found a version of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65114848/find-5-largest-values-in-a-matrix), which unfortunately does not give the indices, which is important for me. The function should return something which I can convert to a data.table in the format [(Row Index), (Column Index), (Value)].

I would be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: @Maël no need for repro, in the linked post there is a repro, or creating example input is trivial `set.seed(1); m <- matrix(runif(100), nrow = 10)`

Comment: Maybe try dedicated packages: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/iCAMP/versions/1.5.12/topics/maxbigm or https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bigmemory/versions/4.6.1/topics/mwhich-methods

Comment: Have you considered a sparse matrix solution?

Comment: If your matrix is dense then the problem is with R and as Rcpp construct R types it does not help _per se_.  You can use Rcpp to construct non-R data structures (Armadillio using 64-bit indices) but you have to figure out how to 'fill' that matrix.

Comment: The bigmemory package looks interesting, thank you for the pointer @zx8754. Dirk: my matrix is dense, not sparse, unfortunately. I can calculate and store the dense matrix in R, but I cannot reshape it to long format due to the restriction on the number of rows, thus I want to extract the n maximum values without reshaping. The 64-bit indices in Armadillio would be very helpful for that, but I have no real experience with writing C++ code myself, that's why the question

Comment: @NilsR If it is dense then I fear you may have real problems because essentially _every_ representation of _dense_ linear algebra assumes a contiguous allocation as that is where the performance comes from.  Now 150k squared times eight bytes for a double leads to a total of 180 gb if my math is right.  Do you have a machine with that much ram?

Comment: I can access a machine with ~2TB RAM. It can calculate and store the matrix, the bottleneck is just that I cannot reshape it into a manageable long format. I don't need top performance as long as I can store it and process it within R functionality, more or less

Comment: In that case welcome to learning enough C++ to do this :)  (I just hopped onto a machine with 64gb ram, used `#define ARMA_64BIT_WORD` before the `#include <RcppArmadillo.h>` and allocated a 150k x 50k _integer_ (half the size) matrix (using the form 'n, k, arma::fill::none') of 30gb.  But because your matrix will _not_ compatiable with R you will have to write yourself custom little inserters of pieces that fit into the R world.  In short, "possible" but far from a slam dunk.

Comment: @zx8754 I checked the two packages you referred to: The bigmemory package throws an error 'long vectors not supported yet' when I try to convert my matrix. The iCAMP package, as far as I can see, only provides 1 maximum value, whereas I would need ~10 million. So sadly both don't seem to be solutions

Comment: If efficiency is a question, you can try the `kit::topn` or `collapse::nth` functions

Comment: Good calls re `kit` and `collapse` but as with the points these will only operate on _subsets_ at a time as the overall matrix is too large for R.

Answer (score 4):

Your matrix is only a bit more than 10 times 2^31, so you could divide it into 11 or more parts, find the top n values of each part, then merge those subsets and find the top n values overall.

For example, with a much smaller matrix:

```r
set.seed(123)
dat <- matrix(rnorm(10000), 100,100)

n <- 10    
parts <- 5

# Calculate the size of each part.  I'll assume it's 
# an integer; it's just a little more complicated if not
len <- length(dat)/parts  

# Record the original rows and columns.  We'll be
# treating everything as vectors, but in standard R
# matrices that doesn't require any operations.  If
# you're using dataframes or tibbles or data tables
# you will need to do a conversion.

row <- row(dat)
col <- col(dat)
result <- NULL

for (i in 1:parts) {
  subset <- seq_len(len) + (i-1)*len
  o <- order(dat[subset], decreasing = TRUE)
  keep <- subset[o[1:n]]
  result <- rbind(result, 
                  data.frame(value = dat[keep],
                             row = row[keep],
                             col = col[keep]))
}

# Now get the final value
o <- order(result$value, decreasing = TRUE)
result <- result[o[1:n], ]
result
#>       value row col
#> 41 3.847768  56  82
#> 21 3.715721  95  60
#> 22 3.445992   5  45
#> 11 3.421095  82  30
#> 42 3.397894  61  82
#> 1  3.390371  24  14
#> 2  3.290517  22  17
#> 31 3.275908  36  68
#> 23 3.271783  76  44
#> 3  3.241040  64   2

# Check it:
max(dat)
#> [1] 3.847768
dat[result$row[1], result$col[1]]
#> [1] 3.847768
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the comment. That is probably feasible, but still inefficient and slow. There will be points in the future where I will have more than 150k x 150k, so this will scale poorly. That's why I was asking for explicit Rcpp solutions

Answer (score 4):

A statistical approach should work well here:

1. Take a relatively large, but manageable sample of the elements of your matrix (e.g., `1e6`).
2. Calculate the value of `k` that will give you a large probability (e.g., 99%) that `k`th largest sample value is smaller than the `n`th largest value in your population.
3. Get the linear indices of the values in the matrix that are greater than the value found in step 2.
4. If the number of indices returned in step 3 is less than `n`, return to step 1. Otherwise, return the linear indices of the `n`th largest values whose indices were found in step 3.

Example implementation using `Rfast::nth` in steps 2 and 4:

```
library(Rfast)

topn.idx <- function(x, n) {
  y <- nth(x[sample(length(x), 1e6)], qbinom(0.99, 1e6, n/length(x)), 1, TRUE)
  i <- which(x > y)
  if (length(i) < n) Recall(x, n) else i[nth(x[i], n, n, TRUE, TRUE)]
}
```

Example usage on a `2^30`-by-`3` matrix on an aging laptop with just enough RAM:

```
set.seed(28404888)
x <- matrix(0, 2^30, 3)
for (i in 1:3) x[,i] <- rexp(2^30)
system.time({idx <- topn.idx(x, 3e6L)})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    9.90  118.50  310.62
length(idx)
#> [1] 3000000
range(x[idx])
#> [1]  6.979972 22.252548
```

The desired `data.table` could be had with:

```
dtIdx <- data.table(rI = idx - 1L)[
  , `:=`(rI = rI%%nrow(x) + 1L, cI = rI%/%nrow(x) + 1L, v = x[idx])
]
```

Additional gains may be had by optimizing on the number of samples and the probability of capturing the `n`th largest value, but I suspect they will be rather modest.

---

### Additional Benchmarking

Interestingly, `topn.idx` is faster than `Rfast::nth` (which is faster than  `kit::topn`) on large matrices with fewer than 2^31 elements.

```
library(kit)
set.seed(28404888)

x <- matrix(rexp(1e8), 1e4, 1e4)
idx <- sort(topn.idx(x, 1e6))
identical(idx, sort(as.integer(nth(x, 1e6, 1e6, TRUE, TRUE))))
#> [1] TRUE
identical(idx, sort(topn(x, 1e6, index = TRUE)))
#> [1] TRUE
bench::mark(
  topn.idx = topn.idx(x, 1e6),
  kit = topn(x, 1e6, index = TRUE),
  Rfast = nth(x, 1e6, 1e6, TRUE, TRUE),
  min_iterations = 10,
  check = FALSE
)
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is
#> disabled.
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 topn.idx   460.32ms 482.57ms     1.91      825MB   2.10  
#> 2 kit           5.93s     6.6s     0.153     385MB   0.0765
#> 3 Rfast         1.86s     1.9s     0.524     771MB   0.524
```

Comment: Could you detail the `nth(` call, i.e. x = x[sample, k = qbinom,  num.of.nths = 1, ah, so TRUE is descending?

Comment: Yes. See `?Rfast::nth`. The number of samples that are above the `n/length(x)` proportion of largest values in `x` is a random variable. `qbinom` here gives the 99th quantile of that number.

Comment: Thank goodness for smaller matrices as (2^30, 3) crashed, on my even older SSE4 chip with insufficient, generally about 3x slower,  topn.idx      1.35s  1.37s , kit          16.37s 17.34s, Rfast         4.83s  5.13s, with mem trade off topn.idx 829MB, kit 385MB, Rfast 771MB.

Comment: Everyone be aware that `bench::mark()` uses different units in a column, so 460.32 is actually less than 5.93

Comment: This is a great solution. You might be able to tweak it to be a few percent better by adjusting the 1e6 and 0.99 in the topn.idx function, but I don't have intuition about which way the tweaks should go.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need extra effort to deal with extremely huge matrices.

---

Here is an example with a small matrix, where `quantile` can be used to get the first `n` largest entries of the matrix

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(0)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(30), 5)
n <- 10

th <- quantile(c(mat), 1 - n / length(mat))
idx <- mat >= th
out <- cbind(as.data.frame(which(idx, TRUE)), val = mat[idx]) %>%
  arrange(desc(val))
```

which gives

```
> out
   row col       val
1    5   2 2.4046534
2    3   1 1.3297993
3    4   1 1.2724293
4    1   1 1.2629543
5    2   6 1.0857694
6    4   5 0.8041895
7    1   3 0.7635935
8    1   6 0.5036080
9    4   4 0.4356833
10   5   1 0.4146414
```

Comment: They can't reshape, as they said `"it will have more than 2^31 rows"`

Comment: @zx8754 aha, you are right. I overlooked that statement. I am deleting my answer.

Comment: @zx8754 see my update with `quantile`, where no `reshape` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

No rcpp solution (so speed remains an issue) but to isolate only the top 10 you could:

```
find_and_replace_max <- function(m, runs = 10, indices_max = NULL, values_max = NULL){
  if(runs > 0){
    index_max <- which.max(m)
    indices_max <- c(indices_max, index_max)
    values_max <- c(values_max, max(m))
    m[index_max] <- -Inf
    find_and_replace_max(m, runs - 1, indices_max, values_max)    
  } else {
    data.frame(index = indices_max, value = values_max)
  }
}
```

Example:

```
## create a 1000 x 1000 matrix:
set.seed(123)
n <- 1e3
m <- 1e3

## do ten runs for the top 10:
find_and_replace_max(matrix(rnorm(n*m), n, m), runs = 10)
```

output:

```
>     index    value
1  661312 4.850767
2  651832 4.790390
3  384839 4.759086
4  989980 4.718727
5  309215 4.599884
6  310358 4.560770
7  234371 4.521510
8  599704 4.492426
9  206891 4.438207
10 290630 4.335663
```